# Remove line with particular flag from a pipe delimited file if there is duplicate id column

Tags: unix, awk

Consider a pipe delimited file,

**File**

```
id1|name|address|yes
id2|name|address|yes
id2|name|address|no
id3|name|address|yes
```

The first column is "id" and last is flag.
How do I remove the line with duplicate id (id2) and flag as 'no'?

**Expected output:**

```
id1|name|address|yes
id2|name|address|yes
id3|name|address|yes
```

I tried to use awk to get duplicate

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{cnt[$1]++; next} cnt[$1]>1' file file
```

How do I remove the line?

Note: File would have 1000s of lines and the ids may not be in the sorted order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F'|' '!a[$1]++ && $NF != "no"' file
id1|name|address|yes
id2|name|address|yes
id3|name|address|yes
```

Brief explanation:
`-F'|'`: Set the field separator to `|`.
`!a[$1]++`: True if the 1st column is never seen before
`&&` : AND
`$NF != "no"`: Last column is not equal to `no`.

Comment: !a[$1]++ , looks for the value all over. Is there way to restrict to check only in the first column?

Comment: $1 should look for 1st column only, are you sure you are setting the field separator to `|` properly ?